# get SamAccountName from large AD groups with DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am using the below approach to query members from large AD groups.

```
try
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=My Distribution List,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com");
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";

    uint rangeStep = 1000;
    uint rangeLow = 0;
    uint rangeHigh = rangeLow + (rangeStep - 1);
    bool lastQuery = false;
    bool quitLoop = false;

    do
    {
        string attributeWithRange;
        if(!lastQuery)
        {
            attributeWithRange = String.Format("member;range={0}-{1}", rangeLow, rangeHigh);
        }
        else
        {
            attributeWithRange = String.Format("member;range={0}-*", rangeLow);
        }           
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attributeWithRange);
        SearchResult results = searcher.FindOne();
        foreach(string res in results.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(res.ToString());
        }
        if(results.Properties.Contains(attributeWithRange))
        {
            foreach(object obj in results.Properties[attributeWithRange])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
                if(obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(System.String)))
                {
                }
                else if (obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(System.Int32)))
                {
                }
                Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            if(lastQuery)
            {
                quitLoop = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastQuery = true;
        }
        if(!lastQuery)
        {
            rangeLow = rangeHigh + 1;
            rangeHigh = rangeLow + (rangeStep - 1);
        }
    }
    while(!quitLoop);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception ex.
}
```

Here I would like to retrieve SamAccountName of members as well along with their distinguishedName.Also I have some groups which contains cross domain members. Could you please help.

Comment: Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Could you post your final version? Did the answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

To get a value of any attribute you typically need to call DirectoryEntry.Properties[*PropertyName*].Value, e.g.

```
var x = results.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value
```

For some indexed values it might be required to provide an index Properties[*PropertyName*][X].Value

If value is not populated by default in result, you might need to force it to load using DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(*PropertyName*);